# jQuery - Loop through div's extracting url from one link then adding it to another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, loops

I need to create a function that gets the url from one link and applies it to another within the same div. I can get it to loop through but it always assigns the last variable to all of the links.

Here is the code :

```
$.fn.getLink = function() { 

    $('a.firstlink').each(function(){

         var linkHref= $(this).attr('href');

         ('a.secondlink').attr('href', linkHref)

    });

}

$('div.containing-links').each(function(){

    $(this).getLink();

});
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks for your quick answers, to make it a bit simpler here is the code that adds the link correctly **but repeats the last href variable** to all of them:

$('a.firstlink').each(function(){

```
var linkHref= $(this).attr('href');

$('a.secondlink').attr('href', linkHref);

    });
```

How can I apply this to **each one at a time?**

Comment: Can you post HTML in question. It's kind of hard to get what you are aiming at.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `$('a.secondlink')` grabs all of the links on the page.  just because it is inside the each loop does not mean it is scoped to anything.

Just change `$('a.secondlink').attr('href', linkHref)` to look something like `$(this).siblings('a.secondlink').attr('href', linkHref);`

Comment: This is not working for me but I think you have got the right idea that its applying the href to all links. When I alert(linkHref); it goes through each one sucessfully.

Comment: overlooked that one, this is the correct answer though there is a better way to do a search in particular context `$('a.firstLink', this)`
you can pass context for element search as a 2nd parameter for jquery selector.

Comment: @Tom, that is a nice feature, but since he's looping through links, not containers, it's not necessarily viable.

Comment: @areid my example probably doesn't work because I don't know your DOM structure, and the links are not direct siblings.  The concept remains the same, you just need to figure out the correct traversal method to the link you want (instead of using the `.siblings()` method.)

Comment: @Stephen it is viable as he is replacing links which are wrapped by a div container `div.containing-links` on which he calls the .each() method to replace these links in every of these wrappers - check my answer below where I've put your answer fix with the use of context on the structure I believe he is aiming at.

Comment: Oh, Sorry @Tom.  I was fixated on the first loop through the `.firstlink` anchors!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good spot to write a plugin. You should do it straightforward in your `.each() loop`.

```
$('div.containing-links').each(function(){
    var $self    = $(this),
        $first   = $self.find('a.firstlink'),
        $second  = $self.find('a.secondlink');

    if( $first.length && $second.length )
        $second[0].href = $first[0].href;
});
```